# How to use behaviors in Polymer v1.0 to extend a polymer element?

Tags: inheritance, polymer-1.0, behavior

I am migrating my code from v0.5 to v1.0. I have a piece of code which reads like this

```
<polymer-element name="submenu-button" extends="paper-icon-button" noscript>
    <template>
        <shadow></shadow>
        <content></content>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

in v1.0 it is changed to the below structure

```
<dom-module id="submenu-button">
  <template>
        <shadow></shadow>
        <content></content>
    </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'submenu-button',
      extends: 'paper-icon-button'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

How can I achieve the `extends: 'paper-icon-button'` functionality using behaviors?

I tried `behaviors: ['paper-icon-button']` but didn't work.

I'm new to js and web development, so maybe I'm missing something out from https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html.

Comment: Firstly, in Polymer 1.0 you can only extend native HTML elements and not custom elements (this may be enabled in the future). Secondly, there is a great video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrlmieL3Z0k) on Polymer behaviors. if you look at the [documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-icon-button) for the `paper-icon-button` element, you can see that it implements `Polymer.PaperInkyFocusBehavior` which is a behavior that you can implement in your `submenu-button`

Comment: You will first need to import the behaviour: `<link rel="import" href="bower_compoenents/paper-behaviors/paper-inky-focus-behavior.html">` and then implement it in your element: `behaviors: [Polymer.PaperInkyFocusBehavior]`.

Comment: Thanks Ben for pointing out the right way to use behaviors !